# WEBRick stays booting for an indefinite amount of time, no error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu-12.04, webrick

I'm trying to execute `rails s -e production` on an installation of [OpenCongress](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/opencongress) inside a Vagrant box (Ubuntu precise64) that already works in development mode. When I try to run the server in production I get this:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.20 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
** [Raven] Raven 0.7.1 ready to catch errors
```

Where it stays for an indefinite amount of time. I can't access the app at `localhost:3000`, and given the fact that there's no error message, I can't diagnose what is going on.

The app runs on a Postgres DB, the production table specified in `database.yml` exists in the DB. I sincerely don't know what's going on.

**EDIT:** Commenting out the gems particular to production in the Gemfile doesn't have any effect whatsoever. Also, trying to run the app with Thin by executing `bundle exec thin -e production` stays on the Raven message too, and after this the process is not killable (sending the `Ctrl-C`signal shows an "Stopping..." message that does not go away).

Answer (score 0):

You are using [this gem](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby).  I would read up on the different configurations to get the behavior you want.